# Is there a mistake in a GRE preparation book?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations, gre-exam

**Preface:**

I am preparing for the GRE Math subject test, and one of the books that I use is [this one](https://isidore.co/CalibreLibrary/Rambo,%20Charles/Practice%20for%20the%20GRE%20Math%20Subject%20Test!%20&%20Bootcamp%20Problems%20&%20GRE%20Mathematics%20Subject%20Test%20GR17%20(7328)/Practice%20for%20the%20GRE%20Math%20Subject%20Test!%20&%20-%20Rambo,%20Charles.pdf) by Charles Rambo. I have currently been solving through the “Linear Algebra #1” section of the book, and there is one problem that I think has an incorrect answer in the solutions section. Let me state the problem as it was drawn in the book:

Let $V$ be the set of all possible polynomials $p(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. And let the linear operators $T$ and $S$ be defined over $V$ as follows:
$$
T(p(x)) = xp(x)
\\
S(p(x)) = \frac{d}{dx}p(x) = p’(x) 
$$
We denote $ST$ and $TS$ as the expected compositions $S\circ T(p(x))$ and $T \circ S(p(x))$ respectively. Which of the following is true?

1. $ST = 0$
2. $ST = T$
3. $ST = TS$
4. $ST - TS$ is the identity map of $V$
5. $ST + TS$ is the identity map of $V$

**My attempt:**

In my opinion, the correct option is (4), since:

1. $ST = \frac{d}{dx}\left[xp(x)\right] = x’p(x) + xp’(x) = p(x)+xp’(x)$
2. $TS = x \cdot \frac{d}{dx}p(x) = xp’(x)$
3. $F(p(x)) = (ST-TS)(p(x))$ is a transformation defined over $V$, then $F(p(x)) = (ST - TS)(p(x)) = p(x)+xp’(x)-xp’(x) = p(x)$, hence $F : V \mapsto V$, in other terms $F$ forms an identity map over $V$.

**Book’s solution:**

In fact, the only thing written in the book about this problem (page 84 in the pdf) was that the answer is (5), and that one had to use the product rule to obtain the correct answer (no explicit solution given).

And so I wonder whether there is any fallacy in my logic above, or it is the book, which is mistaken.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you are correct, the book is mistaken

Comment: You could also confirm the mistake by calculating $ST+TS$ at a specific simple polynomial to see that $5$ fails.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone!

Comment: It  can be shown 5 is an identity for a subset of V. Constant functions.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician (I'm an engineer), but @jjagmath's trick of testing with a simple polynomial (or something similar to that) is something that I regularly use when verifying something that is stated to be true.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer:

You are correct. The book's solution is incorrect.

The part of the book's solution that says to use the product rule is correct -- that is what you correctly did -- but this justifies answer 4, not 5.

It could be a sign error by the author or a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is correct. There is a typo in the pdf's solution. That said, this isn't from my practice booklet and I don't have the LaTeX markup for this document so I can't fix the error. My view is that overall the pdf where this is from is a great resource so it will remain on my website.

Charles Rambo